# Django - How can I get a child type object from a parent class object using MTI?

Tags: python, django, inheritance, multi-table-inheritance

I have a function, `get_priority()`, which sorts through all objects in a parent class (Chunk) to get the highest 'priority' object. Now I want to get the related subclass object to the superclass object.

The [Django docs on Multi-Table Inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) show that I can do this by using the lowercase name of the subclass. For example, if the subclass was Concept I could do the following:

```
chunk = get_priority(Chunk.objects.all())
chunk.concept
```

However, the subclass could be Concept, Code, Formula or Problem. Is the only way to approach this to use try/except for each subclass, e.g.:

```
chunk = get_priority(Chunk.objects.all())
    try: 
         object = chunk.concept
    except:
        pass
    try:
        object = chunk.code
    except:
        pass
    # etc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's not the best way to check what kind of child it is, or at least the most simple.

I guess you have your custom method to get the Chunk priority on `get_priority()` (Personally I would put it on the Chunk objects manager), so to get the correct child I would do this:

```
chunk = get_priority(Chunk.objects.all())

object = None
for attr in ('concept', 'code', 'formula', 'problem'):
    if hasattr(chunk, attr):
        object = getattr(chunk, attr)
```

At the end you will have the child in the `object` variable, or `None` if it has no child, then you can play with the result in the `object` like throw an exception if not child found or just `pass`.

Answer (score 0):

I deduce that Chunk objects have a priority attribute.
If this is true, for sorting the queryset of Chunks you should use:

```
Chunk.objects.order_by('-priority')
```

And refering to the question itself, take a look to: [Specifying the parent link field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#specifying-the-parent-link-field). You could set the same reference name for all subclases.

Futhermore I will advice you to take into acount the advice of two scopes of django:

> Multi-table inherance , sometimes called "concrete inherance" is considered by the authors and many other developers to be a bad thing. We strongly recomend against using it.